# Why am I getting such strange results for time series analysis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, time-series, statsmodels

I am trying to build a model to predict communication quality. Here are the data:[Datalist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBL1N.png)

Next, I plot the 'ds' from 'y', their ACF and PACF, and also consider the Dickey-Fuller criterion.
[plot and ACF/PACF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjlAJ.png)

Code:

```
def tsplot(y, lags=None, figsize=(20, 8), style='bmh'):
    if not isinstance(y, pd.Series):
        y = pd.Series(y)
    with plt.style.context(style):    
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
        layout = (2, 2)
        ts_ax = plt.subplot2grid(layout, (0, 0), colspan=2)
        acf_ax = plt.subplot2grid(layout, (1, 0))
        pacf_ax = plt.subplot2grid(layout, (1, 1))
        y.plot(ax=ts_ax)
        ts_ax.set_title('Time Series Analysis Plots')
        smt.graphics.plot_acf(y, lags=lags, ax=acf_ax, alpha=0.5)
        smt.graphics.plot_pacf(y, lags=lags, ax=pacf_ax, alpha=0.5
        print("Dickey-Fuller test: p=%f" % sm.tsa.stattools.adfuller(y)[1])
        plt.tight_layout()
    return
tsplot(new_data.y, lags=30)
```

The Dickey-Fuller test is 0.003064 and shows that the series is stationary. From the graph of the ACF series, I determined that there is daily seasonality.

Additionally, I applied the Box-Cox transformation. Then, after this, the Dickey-Fuller value is 0.001130, and the optimal Box-Cox transformation parameter is -0.750347.

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYzB3.png)

Code:

```
def invboxcox(y,lmbda):
    if lmbda == 0:
        return(np.exp(y))
    else:
        return(np.exp(np.log(lmbda*y+1)/lmbda))

    data = new_data.copy()
    data['y_box'], lmbda = scs.boxcox(data.y)
    tsplot(data.y_box, lags=30)
    print("Box-Cox: %f" % lmbda)
```

I did not notice any differences. Then I began to select the parameters and build the SARIMA model.

```
ps = range(0, 5)
d=1
qs = range(0, 3)
Ps = range(0, 2)
D=1
Qs = range(0, 2)

from itertools import product

parameters = product(ps, qs, Ps, Qs)
parameters_list = list(parameters)
len(parameters_list)
%%time
results = []
best_aic = float("inf")
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

for param in parameters_list:
    try:
        model=sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(data.y, order=(param[0], d, param[1]), 
                                        seasonal_order=(param[2], D, param[3], 12)).fit(disp=-1)
    except ValueError:
        print('wrong parameters:', param)
        continue
    aic = model.aic
    if aic < best_aic:
        best_model = model
        best_aic = aic
        best_param = param
    results.append([param, model.aic])
```

[Result model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXPwC.png)

After that, I built a chart with leftovers:
[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LLFy.png)

Student's test: 0.634913

Dickey-Fuller test: 0.000000

But when I plot, it shows a constant line at zero:

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDoQA.png)

Code:

```
data['model'] = invboxcox(best_model.fittedvalues, lmbda)
plt.figure(figsize(20,8))
data.y.plot()
data.model[13:].plot(color='r')
plt.ylabel('LQ')
pylab.show()
```

Please help solve my problem!

[Link on file my project:](https://mega.nz/file/2dQAXa5T#K66czqPjMysIHXe4CV7rf_jzxFpKtrAoiFJ9OzT5pew)